# How to embed Youtube video in Javascript alert popup?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm trying to work out how best to embed a Youtube video into a Javascript function so it will appear (and be playable) in a popup alert box.

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<script>
function myFunction12() {
    alert("");
}
</script>
```

And the video I'm trying to insert is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWdQbxNEFEs&frags=pl%2Cwn

I've been trying to use the embed code provided by Youtube in the alert quotations, but it doesn't recognize HTML there and I'm not sure how to proceed. The video needs to appear and play in a popup box.

Thanks much in advance for any tips! I'm pretty new at writing Javascript and may ask follow up questions.

EDIT: I'm now working on creating a modal box that pops up with the video in it when the user clicks "[1](http://w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKTC5KYZEEL)" on the imagemap. I think the components are correct, but I can't quite get the two to connect. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My code is here: [w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKTC5KYZEEL](http://w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKTC5KYZEEL)

Comment: That's not possible. An `alert()` only accepts one string parameter that will be displayed in the alert. If you want more freedom, you'll have to create some custom modal instead of the build-in `alert()` function.

Comment: Not possible. Try googling "how to create pop up in javascript"

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. Can you think of something else I could make that would simulate the same? Also, it it possible to embed links in Java popups? That could be a potential workaround

Comment: to make a video popup just replace the contents with your video 
    https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Comment: This is great Faizal, thank you. Do you know how I might get the modal to pop up without the use of a button? I'm making an imagemap, and I would like to assign the modal with the video in it to one of the clickable rectangles.

Comment: just use cut the id (id="myBtn") and paste it to the clickable rectangle

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save. This is the real one: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKTC5KYZEEL

Comment: These days, you should consider `<dialog>`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: Thanks for this, Brad. I hadn't heard of <dialog> before. Do you know how I might execute this using my current code?

Answer (score 1):

## You Can't; Use a Modal Instead

To my knowledge, it is not possible to embed a video in the alert popup as it only displays plaintext. Youtube embeds are created by using an iframe element which means that the video can't be placed in a traditional Javascript `alert()` popup.

Instead, if you want to have a video you should probably have some Javascript that either creates or unhides an element that contains the video you want. If the video isn't constant, you can set it's url with javascript as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for this information! Do you know how I might accomplish this with my current code? I've updated the post with a link.

Comment: @Zoe just add a function that matches the onclick attribute of the `<area>` tag. Right now the onclick attribute calls a function called "myBtn()" but that function doesn't yet exist. It should probably look something like this: `function myBtn(){ modal.style.display="block" }` but you can name the function whatever you want as long as it matches the onclick attribute.

Comment: Oh, also remove the `href` attribute from the `<area>` tag as it causes the page to redirect to an empty page. Here are the changes implemented in your code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKYZ2IAHM3F

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I've removed the "href" so that issue is solved. Do you know how I would use the modal without the presence of the myBtn? Everytime I try to delete it, the modal opens but won't close. Also, how would one create two or more different modals on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ALertifyJS. You can click outside. You have to use the Youtube Dialogue Alert. I used the CDN in the snippet below. Download Link --

https://alertifyjs.com/build/alertifyjs.zip

```js
alertify.YoutubeDialog || alertify.dialog('YoutubeDialog', function() {
  var iframe;
  return {
    // dialog constructor function, this will be called when the user calls alertify.YoutubeDialog(videoId)
    main: function(videoId) {
      //set the videoId setting and return current instance for chaining.
      return this.set({
        'videoId': videoId
      });
    },
    // we only want to override two options (padding and overflow).
    setup: function() {
      return {
        options: {
          //disable both padding and overflow control.
          padding: !1,
          overflow: !1,
        }
      };
    },
    // This will be called once the DOM is ready and will never be invoked again.
    // Here we create the iframe to embed the video.
    build: function() {
      // create the iframe element
      iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.frameBorder = "no";
      iframe.width = "100%";
      iframe.height = "100%";
      // add it to the dialog
      this.elements.content.appendChild(iframe);

      //give the dialog initial height (half the screen height).
      this.elements.body.style.minHeight = screen.height * .5 + 'px';
    },
    // dialog custom settings
    settings: {
      videoId: undefined
    },
    // listen and respond to changes in dialog settings.
    settingUpdated: function(key, oldValue, newValue) {
      switch (key) {
        case 'videoId':
          iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newValue + "?enablejsapi=1";
          break;
      }
    },
    // listen to internal dialog events.
    hooks: {
      // triggered when the dialog is closed, this is seperate from user defined onclose
      onclose: function() {
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
      },
      // triggered when a dialog option gets update.
      // warning! this will not be triggered for settings updates.
      onupdate: function(option, oldValue, newValue) {
        switch (option) {
          case 'resizable':
            if (newValue) {
              this.elements.content.removeAttribute('style');
              iframe && iframe.removeAttribute('style');
            } else {
              this.elements.content.style.minHeight = 'inherit';
              iframe && (iframe.style.minHeight = 'inherit');
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
//show the dialog
alertify.YoutubeDialog('GODhPuM5cEE').set({
  frameless: true
});
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" />
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.rtl.min.css" />
```

AlertifyJS by Mohammad Younes